# Background image auto resize/scale issue in flash cs5.5 AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

The name of the background image movie clip symbol is bg_main. The problem here is img is aligning outside the browser window on extreme bottom-right hand side instead of centering.
Here's the screenshot link:http://i40.tinypic.com/29cklds.jpg
Here's the code below:

```
//set stage for FBF
stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";

//define dynamic aspect ratios
var bg_mainHeight = bg_main.height / bg_main.width;
var bg_mainWidth = bg_main.width / bg_main.height;

//add event listener to the stage
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, sizeListener);

//conditional statement to account for various initial browswer sizes and proportions
function scaleProportional():void {
    if ((stage.stageHeight / stage.stageWidth) < bg_mainHeight) {
        bg_main.width = stage.stageWidth;
        bg_main.height = bg_mainHeight * bg_main.width;
    } else {
        bg_main.height = stage.stageHeight;
        bg_main.width = bg_mainWidth * bg_main.height;
    };  
}

//center bg_mainture on stage
function centerbg_main():void {
    bg_main.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
    bg_main.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
}

// make listener change bg_mainture size and center bg_mainture on browser resize
function sizeListener(e:Event):void {
    scaleProportional();
    centerbg_main();
}

//run initial locations and size
scaleProportional();
centerbg_main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at where the anchor point is for the movieclip? that could be your problem...

Comment: It's set at the default center however, I tried changing it to other locations but it didn't had any effects on its position.

Comment: have you also tried giving specific x and y position?...
try adding that to your centerbg_main()

Comment: I got the solution: <br> Changing 'code' bg_main.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
 bg_main.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
   to bg_main.x = stage.stageWidth / 1000;
 bg_main.y = stage.stageHeight / 1000;

Comment: glad you got it to work... why are you trying to center a background image that scales? you have it set to TL align, which means it's going to try to scale from there, meaning if you attach your clip to x = 0, and y = 0; should mean that the clip is anchored there and will scale height and width.

Comment: Thanks, drew for your help!! As I mentioned above I did tried to change anchor point to different locations but it didn't affected the position of the background image inside browser.